# Tkinter & X11: Run Program Outside of IDE?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, x11

Quick question on Tkinter & X11: How do I run/operate standalone programs? Here's a (pitifully) simple example,

```
from Tkinter import *
import urllib2
import re

master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

def yahoo_search_condenser():
    n = e.get()
    source = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + n)
    target = source.read()
    expr = re.findall('(?<="yschttl spt"\shref=")[\S]+', target)
    source.close()
    root = Tk()
    text = Text(root)
    text.insert(INSERT, expr)
    text.insert(END, '.')
    text.pack()
    root.mainloop()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=yahoo_search_condenser)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

So how would I launch that without going through my IDE? How does one install/implement an X11 GUI without going through some middleman every time? Obviously, I'm very new to this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. start terminal 2. go to the directory where your script is located 3. type `python name_of_your_script` 4. hit enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with Tkinter at all, but I just copied your code into a file locally and typed `python myfile.py` from the bash shell, and it worked with no problem.